# How do I make the expansion-panel open only on clicking collapse icon on the right?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

How do I make this expansion-panel open content only on clicking icon?
Tried using `readonly` but it didn't help.
Thanks in advance!

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels#expansion-panel
[image]

Comment: I am afraid it's not possible because the library doesn't expose any API to achieve that. Even if you try to play around with `v-model` and `readonly` attributes, everytime `readonly` sets to false, the entire list will become clickable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can put online the argument in all **collapse** like: `expanded={!expanded}`

and in the **icon** you put the `onClick={toggle}`

Comment: Can you explain a little more about this approach?

Comment: Please add more information. Where should I put what??

Answer (score 2):

To make the expansion-panel open only on clicking icon you can use css that disables all clicks on the header and only allows clicks on the icon:

```
<style>
.v-expansion-panel-header{
  pointer-events: none;
}
.v-expansion-panel-header__icon{
  pointer-events: All;
}
</style>
```

Keep in mind if you are using scoped style you have use >>>:
https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Here is the template example, I added @click to provide btn like experience when user clicks on an icon, it's not necessary:

```
<template>
  <v-expansion-panel>
    <v-expansion-panel-header>
      <template #actions>
          <v-icon class="icon Icon Icon--32 icon-utility-arrows-carrot_down-32" 
          @click/>
      </template>
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
    <v-expansion-panels >
      <v-expansion-panel-content >
       <!--content here-->
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panels>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</template>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and just found a solution for that.

You need to implement a custom button on the expansion panel, so it will accept custom events. You can achieve that using **template** and **v-slot**:

```js
  <v-expansion-panel @click.prevent="onClick()">
    <v-expansion-panel-header>

      ...your expansion panel code here

      <template v-slot:actions>
        <v-btn icon @click.stop="onClick()">
          <v-icon>mdi-filter-variant</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>

    </v-expansion-panel-header>
  </v-expansion-panel>
```

...and your `onClick` method would be like this:

```js
    onClick() {
      /*this will toggle only by icon click. at the same time, will prevent toggle 
      by clicking on header. */


      const curr = this.panel
      this.panel = curr === undefined ? 0 : undefined
    }
```

It may seem a little magical that the same function is toggling on icon click and preventing toggle on header click, but this happens because the custom icon button does not toggle itself, so we force that using the `onClick` method. On the other hand, the expansion panel header has its native property of toggling the panel. So when we click it, its value will automatically change and we need to change it back to what it was before the click.